# How to scrape the URL, Title, and Description of Google Search Results

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium to first ask Google a question and then scrape the first few results. I'm trying to add all URLs, Titles, and Descriptions to a Dict which I can then access later. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work - returns 'No Data Found'. Does anyone have an idea of what may be the issue?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

def googleSearch(query):
    # specifing browser web driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='chromedriver')
    
    # search query
    search_engine = "https://www.google.com/search?q="
    query = query.replace(" ","+")
    driver.get(search_engine + query + "&start=" + "0")

    # stored data
    # which will be returned by this function
    data = {}
    
    # number of search reasult count of first page
    s_len = 5
    
    for s_block in range(s_len):

        # result block
        content_block_xpath = f'''//*[@id="yuRUbf"]/div[{s_block}]/div/div'''

        # xpaths
        xpath_url = f"""{content_block_xpath}/div[1]/a"""
        xpath_title = f"""{content_block_xpath}/div[1]/a/h3"""
        xpath_description = f"""{content_block_xpath}/div[2]/span/span"""
        
        try:
                        
            # store data collected of each s_block to block {}
            block = {}

            # find url of content
            url = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_url)
            url = url.get_attribute('href')

            links.append(url.get('href'))
            # find domain name of web having content
            pattern =  r"""(https?:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9-_]+\.)?([a-z0-9-_]+\.[a-z0-9-_]+))"""
            domain = re.search(pattern, url)[0]
            print(links)

            # find title of content
#            title = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_title)
            title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_title)
            title = title.get_attribute("innerText")
            
            # find description of content
#            description = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_description)
            description = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_description)
            description = description.get_attribute("innerText")

            # save all data to block {}
            block["domain"] = domain
            block["url"] = url
            block["title"] = title
            block["description"] = description

            # save block dictionary to main dictionary
            data[f'{s_block}'] = block
        
        except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            continue
        
        if len(data) == 0:
            raise Exception("No data found")

    driver.close()
    return data

def getQuery():
    query = str('How to change a car tire')
    link = googleSearch(query)
    print(link)

getQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

a mix-up with class and id regarding the use of "yuRUbf"

indexing in xpath starts at 1 and not 0

I also don't get the same hierarchical structure as you, but that's just a tweak.
The following produces reasonable results for me:

```
content_block_xpath = f'''(//*[@class="yuRUbf"])[{s_block}]'''

xpath_url = f"""{content_block_xpath}/a"""
xpath_title = f"""{content_block_xpath}/a/h3"""
xpath_description = f"""{content_block_xpath}/a//cite/span"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library to scrape Google Search without Selenium web driver as the data is not processed through JS and it will speed up the script.

Here's how you can extract title, link and a snippet (description) from Google search results using `bs4` and `requests` packages:

```py
params = {
    "q": "How to change a car tire",    # query example
    "hl": "en",                         # language
    "gl": "uk",                         # country of the search, UK -> United Kingdom
    "start": 0,                         # number page by default up to 0
    #"num": 100                     # parameter defines the maximum number of results to return.
}
html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    
for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
    title = result.select_one(".DKV0Md").text
    try:
       snippet = result.select_one(".lEBKkf span").text
    except:
       snippet = None
    links = result.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]
```

You can also extract not only the first page, but all the rest using pagination whith infinite `while` loop.

In this case, pagination is possible as long as the next button exists (determined by the presence of a button selector on the page, in our case the CSS selector `.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]`, you need to increase the value of ["start"] by 10 to access the next page (this may be called as [non-token pagination](https://python.plainenglish.io/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#5a76)), if present, otherwise, we need to exit the while loop:

```py
if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
    params["start"] += 10
else:
    break
```

Check code in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-search-pagination-bs4#main.py)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "How to change a car tire",    # query example
    "hl": "en",                         # language
    "gl": "uk",                         # country of the search, UK -> United Kingdom
    "start": 0,                         # number page by default up to 0
    #"num": 100                         # parameter defines the maximum number of results to return.
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    page_num += 1
    print(f"page: {page_num}")
        
    html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    
    for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
        title = result.select_one(".DKV0Md").text
        try:
           snippet = result.select_one(".lEBKkf span").text
        except:
           snippet = None
        links = result.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]
      
        data.append({
          "title": title,
          "snippet": snippet,
          "links": links
        })
      
    if soup.select_one(".d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]"):
        params["start"] += 10
    else:
        break
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "How Long Do Tires Last and When Should I Replace Them?",
    "snippet": "As a general rule, we recommend every 5,000-7,000 miles, but it depends on numerous factors, including your car's alignment. You can read more on The Drive's ...",
    "links": "https://www.thedrive.com/cars-101/35041/how-long-do-tires-last"
  },
  {
    "title": "Car Tire Valve Stem Replacement - iFixit Repair Guide",
    "snippet": "Step 1 Car Tire Valve Stem · Locate the stem valve and remove the cap. · Using the Schrader valve core bit in your 1/4\" driver, unscrew the valve core from the ...",
    "links": "https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Car+Tire+Valve+Stem+Replacement/121415"
  },
  other results ...
]
```

---

Also you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import json, os

params = {
  "api_key": "...",                  # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
  "engine": "google",                # serpapi parser engine
  "q": "How to change a car tire",   # search query
  "gl": "uk",                        # country of the search, UK -> United Kingdom
  "num": "100"                       # number of results per page (100 per page in this case)
  # other search parameters: https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)      # where data extraction happens

organic_results_data = []
page_num = 0

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()    # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
    page_num += 1
    
    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        organic_results_data.append({
            "title": result.get("title"),
            "snippet": result.get("snippet"),
            "link": result.get("link")
        })
    
    if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))
    else:
        break
    
print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
    "title": "Today: can you safely change a tire with passengers on board?",
    "snippet": "RAY: In any case, the primary danger during a tire change is that the vehicle will slip off the jack and injure the tire changer.",
    "link": "https://www.cartalk.com/content/today-can-you-safely-change-tire-passengers-board"
  },
  {
    "title": "How to Change a Flat Tire - Mercedes-Benz Burlington",
    "snippet": "How to Switch a Tire in 5 Steps · Secure the wheel wedges against the tires on the opposite side of the flat tire. · Remove the hubcap or wheel ...",
    "link": "https://www.mercedes-benz-burlington.ca/how-to-change-a-flat-tire/"
  },
  other results...
]
```